# Как трансляторы хранят AST?

Tags: интерпретатор, транслятор

Изучаю тему создания ЯП. Возник такой вопрос:

Интерпретаторы выполняют код строчка за строчкой, но при этом любой интерпретатор выдаст ошибку, не начав исполнение кода, если где-то не закрыта скобка или допущена какая-то другая синтаксическая ошибка. Из этого я сделал вывод, что код выполняется не на лету, а после синтаксического анализа. При этом, для скорости работы интерпретатора (да и про компиляторы можно сказать то же самое) было бы логично на стадии этого синтаксического анализа заодно строить AST, а потом уже его исполнять. Так вот сама суть вопроса: не слишком ли много оперативной памяти будет занимать хранение такого AST вообще **всей** программы, в которой может быть очень много тысяч строк кода (да еще и + подключенные библиотеки), или (обобщим) трансляторы применяют какие-то другие трюки? Если да, то какие?

Comment: AST компилируется в байткод, и уже байткод остаётся храниться в памяти

Comment: @andreymal, разве все языки компилируются в байткод?
И если так, то получается, что параллельно с синтаксическим анализом строится AST и компилируется в байткод, и не важно, что там где-то через N строчек может быть не закрыта скобка?

Comment: Насчёт всех языков не знаю, но как минимум Python, Lua (LuaJIT) и JavaScript (V8) используют и интерпретируют именно байткод (который при наличии JIT иногда дополнительно компилируется прямо в машинный код). Байткод создаётся после AST, а если будет не закрыта скобка, то AST не получится и байткода тоже не получится

Comment: Теоретически, наверное, можно придумать такой интерпретатор, которому будет безразлична незакрытая скобка где-то вдалеке, но я таких языков сходу не припомню (разве что bash, но это не совсем ЯП)

Comment: @andreymal, вот я именно об этом: "... а если будет не закрыта скобка, то AST не получится и байткода тоже не получится". Тогда на какой стадии в такой системе будет происходить построение AST в случае именно однопроходного транслятора? Просто если бы не было реальных примеров однопроходных трансляторов (С), вопрос бы отпал сам собой, наверно